# Bitwise query multiples values

Tags: sql, sql-server, bit-manipulation

I want execute a query with bitwise in SQL Server.

I have a Event table with values with all combinations.

If Monday is (2^0) 1, and Sunday is (2^6) 64, I want all records with monday, wednesday and sunday, I write this query:

```
SELECT Distinct(DayBitwise)
FROM Assets
WHERE DayBitwise | 1 | 4 | 64 = 1 | 4 | 64
ORDER BY DayBitwise
```

Expected result:

```
1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13, 15, 17, 19, 20, 21, 23, 25, 27, 28, 29, 31 ....
```

Actual result:
1,4 ,5, 64, 65, 68

Thanks.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function, it's a part of `SELECT DISTINCT`. To make code clearer, simply do `SELECT Distinct DayBitwise FROM ...`

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: what is your input or raw data on which you are expecting above result.

Comment: @alberto see revised answer. BTW, 10 (tue, thu) should not be there.

Comment: Right Salman, I changed it.

Comment: @jarlh thanks, but the result in this case is the same.

Comment: @GordonLinoff How could get the expected result?

Comment: @DarkRob With this query:  "SELECT Distinct PlatformBitwise
FROM Assets
ORDER BY PlatformBitwise" in db i have this data: 1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
27
28
29
30
31
32
48
63
64
65
68
96
97
98
127

Comment: @AlbertodeVargas, you missed the point. Your parentheses enclosing the column name makes no difference at all. The right way is `SELECT DISTINCT DayBitwise FROM ...`, but you can add any number of matching pairs of parentheses, like `SELECT DISTINCT (((DayBitwise))) FROM ...` etc, which makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to see if all three days are present, then do:

```
WHERE (DayBitwise & 1 & 4 & 64) = (1 | 4 | 64)
```

If you want any, then:

```
WHERE (DayBitwise & (1 | 4 | 64)) > 0
```

Note:  I don't recommend using bit columns for this purpose.  Bit operations are not particularly efficient in SQL.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're interested in checking if any of the monday, wednesday or sunday bit is set you need to use AND mask and that the result is non-zero:

```
WITH assets(DayBitwise) AS (
    SELECT number
    FROM master..spt_values
    WHERE type = 'p' AND number BETWEEN 0 AND 127
)
SELECT *
FROM assets
WHERE DayBitwise & (1 | 4 | 64) <> 0
```

Answer (score 0):

If everything else is fine then probably this would be your answer

```
    go

    SELECT Distinct DayBitwise FROM Assets 
    WHERE DayBitwise | 1 | 4 | 64 = 1 | 4 | 64
    ORDER BY DayBitwise

     go
```

If it is not working then kindly share the error message.

Comment: The response is not an error, but the actual result is:
1,4 ,5, 64, 65, 68